# Why do I have two res folders in my project?

Tags: android

I believe it has something to do with me importing a project of the same name (working from different computers), but I really don't know. Within the bin folder of my project is another res folder, containing AndroidManifest, classes.dex, jarlist.cache, R.txt, resource.ap_ and the apk of my application.

Incidentally, or not, when trying to update my application icon, it only worked when changing the manifest in this version as well.

Comment: The `bin` folder contains the compiled project that will be packed into the apk file. If you change something you should rebuild your project to update the content of this folder.

Comment: I see, so this is normal, not a problem? I'm unsure why it took me to change the android:icon="@drawable/xx" within that manifest to get it working though.

Comment: Are you sure that you run the build process after the change of the original manifest file?

Comment: it builds automatically doesn't it? since the change I have refreshed the project and cleaned + restarted eclipse multiple times

Answer (score 0):

One of the res folder is auto generated. To check which one is auto generated, click on the res folder and press Alt + Enter. Then select resource on left side of the pop up and on the right side, you will see the location. If it's

```
YourProject\res
```

then it's your original res file and if it's

```
YourProject\bin\res
```

then it's the auto generated res file.

Comment: Ok, so that isn't a problem? It is normal to auto generate this?

Comment: There's no problem at all. It's normal to have auto generated files. You can work normally on your project. I have auto generated Manifest in many of my projects but they run fine.